# Preventing Ajax Lazy Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-performance

I'm trying to split test a site with a variation that prevents the default lazy load of product images from happening, and instead presents a "Load More" button that gives the user control of when to load the images. This is the test page: http://www.dunelm.com/category/home-and-furniture/bedding/bedding-sets

The problem is that it looks like the site is not using an easily accessible plugin for the lazy load. Via the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools I can see the line of code that initiates the AJAX call but it's part of a their main minified javascript file and it's pretty complex. Is this even possible to override?

(http://www.dunelm.com/wcsstore/public/js/main.min.js line 3,863):

```
et.ajaxTransport(function(e) {
    var t;
    return Q.cors || Li && !e.crossDomain ? {
        send: function(i, n) {
            var s, o = e.xhr(), r = ++Pi;
            if (o.open(e.type, e.url, e.async, e.username, e.password),
            e.xhrFields)
                for (s in e.xhrFields)
                    o[s] = e.xhrFields[s];
            e.mimeType && o.overrideMimeType && o.overrideMimeType(e.mimeType),
            e.crossDomain || i["X-Requested-With"] || (i["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest");
            for (s in i)
                o.setRequestHeader(s, i[s]);
            t = function(e) {
                return function() {
                    t && (delete Ai[r],
                    t = o.onload = o.onerror = null ,
                    "abort" === e ? o.abort() : "error" === e ? n(o.status, o.statusText) : n(Di[o.status] || o.status, o.statusText, "string" == typeof o.responseText ? {
                        text: o.responseText
                    } : void 0, o.getAllResponseHeaders()))
                }
            }
            ,
            o.onload = t(),
            o.onerror = t("error"),
            t = Ai[r] = t("abort"),
            o.send(e.hasContent && e.data || null )
        },
        abort: function() {
            t && t()
        }
    } : void 0
}
```